# emacs (plugin) distribution (vim janus alike)

Tags: vim, emacs

I'm a `vim` user currently trying to learn `emacs`. For `vim` there are distributions (although I'm not using any) such as [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) which has all common plugins. Are there anything similar for emacs for newbies like me?

Comment: Emacs has a built in package manager which can install packages easily: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html

Comment: ye and I also realized that emacs is already shipped with a lot of plugins maybe that's why there is no need for a distribution.

Comment: Offtopic question: are you trying emacs because you are not happy with vim or you just want to get comfortable with both?

Comment: I guess I'm just curious. I highly doubt I can give up the finger feel after all this time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at the [emacs starter kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) or [prelude](http://batsov.com/prelude/) for common startup configurations for emacs